# sDNA - shapefile exception Geodesics

Tags: error, geodesic, sdna

When calculating Geodesics with a large number (300 +) of origins and destinations (specified with 0/1 weights on links) I receive the error:

```
`ERR: shapefile.ShapefileException: When saving both the dbf and shp file, the number of records (119809) must correspond with the number of shapes (119810).`
```

Does sDNA have an upper limit of Geodesics it can calculate and store, or is the problem likely elsewhere? I am running sDNA on a MacPro M1 and Windows 11 Parallels. skipzeroweightorigins and skipzeroweightdestinations is set.

Comment: There shouldn't be an upper limit at 110k as I've processed larger networks than that, however, geodesics have a lot of points in so worth checking if you have run out of memory? Also memory in the process, are you running sdna 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Another angle, do you have arcgis installed, if so you could see if the same issue occurs when using gdb files instead of shapefiles.

Comment: Thanks! I will try on Monday with a Windows machine and ArcGIS - I might try to go the OD table way, as this is likely faster (and the OD pairs are defined)

Comment: I tried on a desktop machine and it worked. I found an alternative way via OD Matrix, which seems computationally less demanding. 
Here I noted two things, however:
1) IDs (which are also used as zones, formated as string) in the input file must be ordered and continious. If not, the Orig and Dest IDs will differ as they are ordered, and ID pairs that have changed IDs are dropped. 
2) sDNA in Parallels (M1, Windows 11) does not take Matrix files - Error: Wrong or missing parameter value: Origin Destination Matrix input file. The same command works in Windows ("proper").

Comment: PS - "the Error: Wrong or missing parameter value: Origin Destination Matrix input file" is not due to Parallels but QGIS 3.32. In older versions of sDNA running on Parallels, the error dues not occur.